# Windows Phone 7 set Image Margin using code

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have one image on top of another.In code I am trying to set it's position using int's.I have two random int's representing the top and left.How can I set it's position over the other image do I use the Margin? If so how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Complete use style:

```
image1.Margin = new Thickness(10,50,300,20); //(left, top, right, bottom)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it was `image.Margin = new Thickness();`